# pg_config not found when building PostGIS source on Windows

Tags: windows, postgresql, postgis

I am trying to build the latest stable PostGIS from source on Windows using [this](http://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#PGInstall) documentation. I already have PostgreSQL installed without problems. When I execute the configure script from the PostGIS source, I get this problem:

> configure: error: could not find pg_config within the current path. You may need to re-run configure with a --with-pgconfig parameter.

I get this problem if I specify the pg_config file using

```
$ sh ./configure --with-pgconfig="c:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/pg_config.exe"
```

> configure: error: the user-specified pg_config file c:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/pg_config.exe does not exist

but it does exist...

Does anyone have any suggestion? It is important that I build from source.

Comment: 1) There is a typo: `pg_cofig.exe` 2) Do you get the expected output if you run `"c:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/pg_config.exe"` manually? 3) Could it be a problem with the space in `Program Files` that goes away if you escape it or avoid path names with a space?

Comment: 1) Yes, sorry about that, it's only a type here on SO not in my experiment (updating it).
2) If I just run the pg_config executable it works as intended.
3)I thought the quotes handled that, but I tried escaping the space and still the same problem.

Comment: Sorry, please update link Postgis source you downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in `configure`.

You can see that from this error message:

```
./configure: line 15593: test: "C:\Program: binary operator expected
```

On that line, I see in `configure`:

```
if test -f $PG_CONFIG; then
```

There should be double quotes around that (and other references to `PG_CONFIG`).

I can think of two workarounds:

- Install PostgreSQL in a directory without spaces in the path name.
- Unpack PostGIS in a directory under `C:\Program Files` and run `configure` like this:

  ```
  ./configure --with-pgconfig="../PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/pg_config.exe"
  ```

A [fix has been committed](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/changeset/15313/) to PostGIS, so it should work from release 2.4.0 on.

Comment: Thanks! This hit the nail on the head. Now it asks for PGXS makefile and asks for PostgreSQL server development packages so I suppose I need to install PostgreSQL differently.

Comment: You'll need to install the software package that contains the header files and development environment for PostgreSQL (often called *devel* or similar).

Comment: I have sent a patch to PostGIS, and it has been applied.